# .xsd file in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd

I was watching the tutorial for ReportViewer and Linq to SQL and in this I found the .xsd file, I am unfamiliar from this file please tell me what is this and how can I generate this file.

Comment: An XSD file is an Xml schema. That means, the blueprints for how an XML file 'foo' is going to look. In the context of a report, that would define the Dataset schema. Please read: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/Crystal_Report__90.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML Schema Definition Tool generates XML Schema from XML blocks, among other things: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx

Comment: Eric, please don't post MSDN links with version numbers, unless the answer is specific to the old version.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, thanks for catching that.  I will pay attention in the future.